# How to find the Material of magnet

Tags: ferromagnetism

Is there any way to find out if a magnet is a neodymium, ferrite(ceramic), samarium cobalt or alnico magnet (based on color, texture, etc.)?

Comment: You might have better luck asking this in [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You might try Xray diffraction.

Ceramics are metal oxides, and do non conduct electricity, while the others are metals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! On the Internet, I find most of the images of ferrite magnet to be dark grey while the alnico magnets to be painted. Is this correct?